# webMethods Integration need license file

Tags: webmethods

I'd like to explore webMethods Integration server and downloaded it from http://techcommunity.softwareag.com/ecosystem/communities/public/webmethods/contents/download/ but it asks for a license. Is there a way to start it without one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After requesting the Free Trial you should have received an email containing an installer, installation image file and a 180-day free trial license file.
You probably didn't follow correctly the steps in the Installation guide and haven't clicked on the Advanced options button, so it's asking for Empower (customer) credentials.
What you need to do is:

1. Click Advanced options on the first sceen of the installer
2. Switch the tab to Images
3. Check Install from image and select the path to the installation image file that you've downloaded.
4. When it asks for license select the xml files from the free trial license you've downloaded.

You can refer to the guide here http://techcommunity.softwareag.com/web/guest/pwiki/-/wiki/Main/Guide%20to%20Downloading%20and%20installing%20the%20webMethods%20Free%20Trial%20Version